# Java script procura STRING no HEADER HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom dia amigos! tenho uma duvida referente à um operação que preciso realizar após o envio dos dados de um formulário. Eu possuo um formulário que seus devidos campos para preenchimento e uma função para "submitar" essas informações digitadas:
Minha duvida é a seguinte: após o envio dessas informações, uma pagina será carregada, eu preciso de um js (ou qualquer outro código que atenda) que leia o Header dessa nova pagina e procure o seguinte valor:
"Cookie=1"
Se ele achar este valor, então quero que o usuário seja direcionado para outra URL.

Alguma ideia?

ps: O código abaixo é do envio do formulário, após a execução deste quero que "algo" que leia o header em busca da string que mencionei acima.

```js
submitInputValue: "Enviar",
        setFields: function(e) {
            switch (e) {
                case "login":
                    this.loginFields = !0, this.submitInputValue = "Acessar";
                    break;
                case "pwdWillExp":
                    this.pwdWillExpFields = !0, this.submitInputValue = "Alterar a Senha";
                    break;
                case "changePwd":
                    this.changePwdFields = !0, this.submitInputValue = "Alterar a Senha";
                    break;
                case "pwdNotChanged":
                    this.pwdNotChangedFields = !0, this.submitInputValue = "Alterar a Senha";
                    break;
                case "sessionExpired":
                    this.sessionExpiredFields = !0, this.submitInputValue = "Acessar";
                    break;
                case "acessPrivate":
                    this.accessPrivateFields = !0, this.submitInputValue = "Acessar";
                    break;
                case "solicitPwdChg":
                    this.solicitPwdChgFields = !0, this.submitInputValue = "Alterar a Senha";
                    break;
                default:
                    this.loginFields = !0, this.submitInputValue = "Acessar"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar as funções em PHP ou JS que trabalham com Cookies.

Basicamente você precisa Escrever e Ler um Cookie, assim veja o exemplo abaixo e aplique a sua necessidade.

Exemplo com PHP:

Para **Escrever** um Cookie faça:

```
<?php

//O ultimo parâmetro é o tempo que o Cookie deve ficar no navegador.
setcookie("name_do_cookie", "value", time()+60*60);

?>
```

Para **ler** a informação guardada no Cookie faça:

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["name_do_cookie"];
?>
```

Para apenas **atualizar** faça:

```
<?php
setcookie("name_do_cookie","novo_valor");
?>
```

Para **deletar** faça:

```
<?php
unset($_COOKIE["name_do_cookie"]);
/* ou */
setcookie("name_do_cookie","",time()-1);
?>
```

**Em JS** você pode usar as funções abaixo:

Para criar:

```
<script>
//Criar
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
} 

//Para ler
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
} 

function checkCookie() {
    var username=getCookie("username");
    if (username!="") {
        alert("Welcome again " + username);
    }else{
        username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (username != "" && username != null) {
            setCookie("username", username, 365);
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

Referência:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php